Availability check for IotHub Using Ping C# Does not work ICMP Echo packet in container as the outbound does not allow ICMP
I am trying to check availability of an IoTHub using Ping,
public async Task<bool> CheckAvailabilityAsync(string url)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url)) return false;
    Ping ping = new Ping();
    try
    {
        var result = await ping.SendPingAsync(url);
        return result.Status == IPStatus.Success;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

here url is "notavilableiothubName.azure-devices.net".
look like ICMP is not supported for outbound ! What is the best way to achieve this !  Is there a native availability check for iothubs?

Check IoT Hub service and resource health

Microsoft Azure Resource Health helps you diagnose and get support for service problems that affect your Azure resources

There is nothing mentioned about programmatic way of health check it is all dashboard, say i have disaster recovery service running to check if iot hub is reachable for a region! @Sampath

Could you provide a link to ICMP Echo packets and list all the packages you are using?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping?view=net-8.0
Simple as inbuilt ping i am using.
Assembly System.Net.Ping, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Limitation mentioned here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/outbound-rules#limitations
@Sampath

Alternatively I am planning to use socket connection test.
 try
 {
     using (var socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp) { Blocking = true })
     {
         var task = socket.ConnectAsync(url, 443);
         await task.WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));           
         return true;
     }
 }
 catch (Exception)
 {
     return false;
 }

Supporting ports available documented.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-protocols#port-numbers
Not sure if this is the best way, suggestions welcome!
